# Bazel folder naming convention

Tags: bazel

I know that bazel does not impose any specific file structure, but there are some folder naming conventions that are followed by products using Bazel, and some of them (e.g. "third_party") do have a special treatment (it requires the `licenses` to be specified).

So I don't quite understand the difference between `tools` and `third_party`. For example, if I want to put a "ruby toolchain" it's a tool, since it's the language interpreter, but it's also a third_party, because it has been developed by a community. Where should it go?

And what about bazel rules? Where should the be placed idiomatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a Bazel developer, and I agree, the usage here can be a little confusing.

Generally, we recommend that third_party be used for any external code you're importing to use in your project. Bazel itself, for example, has a lot of libraries in there for Python flag parsing, Java compilation, and a lot of other things.

Tools, on the other hand, would be for code you've written to help with your project as a standalone program. For example, if you wrote a script that converts a static text file into code (maybe so you can access the data as in-language constants), I'd say that could go into tools, since it's a standalone, but useful for your project.

(As a note, Bazel's tools directory is a bit different from this: we actually package those up and include them in the Bazel binary so they can be used at run-time, not at build-time).

If you're writing custom Skylark rules, you can put that wherever makes sense, but I'd like to ask that if you think they might be useful beyond your project, you create a separate repository for them so other developers can use them. It's much easier to use custom rules from a dedicated repository, since you just need to use the http_archive() rule in a WORKSPACE to get them. If they're mixed in with the rest of your project, it's harder for other people to re-use.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation. It makes sense to me. I inspected some google projects in order to understand this better. Since I've had the luck to find a bazel developer can I quickly ask for any existing solution to `pkg_tar` ignoring .runfiles? I cloned bazel locally in order to modify the source code, since I had no luck other than the bug #671 on your BT, but maybe there's already a solution. Otherwise I'm going to open a ticket there.

Comment: I don't know anything off the top of my head about the runfiles issue. It looks like work was happening on issue #671, you could take a look at pull request #2687 (https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/pull/2687) and see if that gets you started.